# Wrong results with Pandas stack/unstack

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Pandas DataFrame:

```
              rnd  non-rnd
first   last              
andrew  wood    0      123
bob     wood    0      234
charlie wood    0      345
```

Can someone explain the difference between the following two operations:

```
In [1]: df.unstack(level=0).stack(level=0)
Out[1]: 
first         andrew  bob  charlie
last                              
wood non-rnd       0    0        0
     rnd         123  234      345
```

and

```
In [2]: df.unstack(level=0).sort_index(axis=1).stack(level=0)
Out[2]: 
first         andrew  bob  charlie
last                              
wood non-rnd     123  234      345
     rnd           0    0        0
```

The first of these is clearly wrong.. Is this a bug? Or am I just using it wrong?

Comment: Wired I have the same situation , but base on the github , it should be fixed https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17225

Comment: OK, I'll close this question and file it as a bug report

Comment: Sure , please :-)

Comment: Oops, it's already there: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21675

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be submitted as a bug report.

Comment: Just need them to fix , and sort_index can be a temporary solution

Comment: It makes me nervous to see this, as it was a fluke that I noticed it in my data..

Comment: Would you like see my solution , When i do stack and unstack ,  I always using stack firstly then unstack

Answer (score 2):

So my solution for this , always using `stack` before `unstack` , make the index or columns became simple index , rather than keep both of them are multiple index. ***(It is bug for sure , see the comments above , there are [two](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17225) [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21675) from the github)***

```
df.stack().unstack(level=0)
Out[125]: 
first         andrew  bob  charlie
last                              
wood rnd           0    0        0
     non-rnd     123  234      345
```

Comment: I'll start doing this in practise for sure! I don't think this answers the actual question though, which is asking why the unstack-before-stack yields the unexpected answer.